# Angular 17 with NX and SSR/ISR (trying to migrate from version 16)

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular17

Been using NX for a while in combination with SSR and ISR. This works perfect in Angular 16 in combination with Angular 17. Now when Angular 17 came out, I migrated my app to a standalone app and it works perfectly fine in Angular 16. So I should be ready to go to Angular 17 in combination with NX.

Unfortunately, I can't get it to work in the way it did. I have the following commands in my package.json now:

```
"dev:ssr": "nx run my-app:serve-ssr",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/server/main.js",
    "build:ssr": "nx run build --skip-nx-cache && nx run my-app:server",
```

And this is a partial of the project.json:

```
"server": {
      "dependsOn": ["build"],
      "executor": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/./server",
        "main": "server.ts",
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.server.json"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "outputHashing": "media"
        },
        "development": {
          "optimization": false,
          "sourceMap": true,
          "extractLicenses": false
        }
      },
      "defaultConfiguration": "production"
    },
```

And in my Plesk environment I run the "build-ssr" command and it just works. I just can't seem to figure out how to do this towards Angular 17 though.

Tried many ways, yet didn't find out **the** way to do this. From NX there doesn't seem to be a clear migration path. I tried the nx migration path, which did update the package.json and Angular versions and also tried to manually update all files by comparing a clean install. But the part that constantly fails is getting it to work on the server (I don't want this to run locally only of course).

I already also have the app.routes.ts, app.config.ts and app.config.server.ts files setup, next to the standalone app.

Someone here to help me out on this one?

Comment: did you find a solution for this? I am about to embark on ssr with micro front ends.  trying to front load the best i can.

Comment: To be honest with you here, I fell back on SSG since I couldn't get it (ISR) to work with NX and Angular 17. Now when Google'ing, I see there could be a potential fix in 17.1 - which I haven't tried. I am on the latest greatest 17.3.1, so I could have another shot. It's just that I didn't try anymore, since this worked for now (although costs a lot of build time for static pages being generated upon build). Can keep you updated later if you'd like me to?